# Necessary to turn on Backbone.emulateJSON when using CakePHP as Backend?

Tags: cakephp, backbone.js

Currently I'm developing a mobile application using backbone.js on the client side and CakePHP as backend. When I tried to use backbone `.save()`-method I realized that nothing was received in `$this-request->data` on the CakePHP side.

This changed when I switch on set to `Backbone.emulateJSON = true`.

Is this correct or is my configuration of CakePHP just plain wrong?

Comment: did you tried sending request to cake framework with cake itself? if that works it should get any request from any where..

Comment: You mean a json_encoded response to cake itself as a test?

Comment: yes. did you tried that? and also check your url request to see if it's correct.